# Kong Basic Auth authorizing a route request using authentication from another service

Tags: basic-authentication, api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

Good Evening,

I've set two two endpoints from different services/routes, they both have authentication via basic-auth with completely different users/pass.
The issue is, i can use any authentications to either of services/routes.

Service1>Route1 user:1 pass:1
Service2>Route2 user:2 pass:2

I can use the user and pass 1 to access the services 1 and 2 and vice-versa

Comment: Can you share your conf, and describe expected behavior compared to the observed one ? I am not sure to understand your issue

Comment: @Ôrel I got working and posted a message about it. Ty for your interest in helping out

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the "issue" was about a misconception about authentication vs authorization.

I had only set up the Basic Auth plugin, so any request made by an authenticated user was getting a response, even if they not supposed to.

What I did to solve, was add the ACL plugin and configure the groups to allow or deny requests on service / route level.